# HP 9050 printer web admin pages extremely slow and often unresponsive

Tags: printer

Our HP 9050 printer web admin pages are extremely slow and often unresponsive.

The printer is on our LAN, on a different subnet. Users can use it without problem. I can ping and telnet to the printer without problem from my workstation. Have done all the usual power cycles etc.

Any ideas on why the web interface is so unusable? I have 10 other printers all working ok.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I don't think that I've seen HP do any user-facing application (including their web apps) that was better than "OK / Somewhat-Functional".  Most, IMHO, stretch the spectrum from "bad / barely-functional" to "WTF".  I love their Server Hardware, and much of their printer lines are satisfactory, but they can't write elegant, functional code.

Answer (score 1):

If ping and telnet work OK, but HTTP access is slow *only* from a routed network then the first place I'd look is to see if the webserver is trying to run ident or reverse DNS lookups. Try grabbing some packets when everyone has gone home.